# Looking for gradient formula or algorithm to return normalized value

Tags: algorithm, function, math, equation

I'm looking for some kind of formula or algorithm that can return a normalized value based on three inputs in a gradient type manner, where you define the hotspot of the gradient where the value is 1, and a roof and floor value where the value drops towards 0 as it gets closer to them.

Ex.

```
GradientFunction(valueToEvaluate, hotspot, roof, floor)

GradientFunction(50, 50, 60, 35) = 1.0
GradientFunction(60, 50, 60, 35) = 0
GradientFunction(35, 50, 60, 35) = 0
GradientFunction(51, 50, 60, 35) = 0.closeto1
GradientFunction(34, 50, 60, 35) = 0.closeto0
```

Is there a math formula that especially works for this of some kind?

Comment: The simplest algorithm would be linear.  In your first example, going from 50 to 60 results in 1 to 0, so 55 would be 0.5.  Going from 50 to 35 results in 1 to 0, so 40 would be 0.333...  The formulas are  (roof - value) / (roof - hotspot) or (value - floor)  / (hotspot - floor), depending on whether the value is above or below the hotspot.

Comment: This worked, thanks. using math absolute it can be one line